# Algolia Places.js throwing error: "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature."

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, typescript-typings

I am importing Algolia's places.js with the following line:

```
import * as places from 'places.js';
```

And further down:

```
const placesAutocomplete = places({
    appId: 'plTI5MDAXXXX',
    apiKey: '7d055eac95a6c48eb4939d2d5edXXXX',
    container: document.querySelector('#address-input')
});
```

And I am getting the following error:

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
>
> Type `typeof import("ionic/XXXX/node_modules/places.js/typings")' has no compatible call signatures.

I already tried installing [DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the import line to:

```
import places from 'places.js';
```

worked on the latest update of the [places.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/places.js) bundle.

FYI: I also had to fix an issue related to types, after faffing around with types for long. This error was popping up, once the aforementioned error was fixed:

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string | HTMLInputElement'.
>   [ng]   Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.

This was fixed by explicitly casting  onto the container:

```
const placesAutocomplete = places({
    appId: 'plTI5MDAXXXX',
    apiKey: '7d055eac95a6c48eb4939d2d5edXXXX',
    // The following change: <HTMLInputElement>
    container: <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('#address-input')
});
```